# How is it that the Inner Periodic Table Sections (have 15 elements each) versus their f-block (with only 14 element’s electrons each)?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

Given:
1.  the “Lanthanide and Actinide” Inner Periodic Table Sections (each have **15 elements**) versus the f-block Orbitals (which only have a capacity for **14 out of the 15 element’s electrons each**) - leaving 1 element’s electrons **each** in the Inner Periodic Table Sections out in the cold. 
2.  the f-block Orbital Structure is different from say the d-block, and not interchangeable.

How do we complete the correct electron configuration notation without substituting the d-block which has its own different unique Orbital Structure for its element’s electrons?

Comment: This is a little confusing to follow could you elaborate?

Comment: at the bottom of every Periodic Table (https://applets.kcvs.ca/IPTEI/IPTEI.html) you will find the section for the “Lanthanide and Actinide” Inner Periodic Table Sections - bearing  the 1st element name for each of the 2 Inner rows of 15 elements each - which are squeezed into rows 6 & 7, column 3.

Comment: If you check out YouTube's "Electron Configurations: Writing Condensed and Expanded Versions" URL "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5omUQRmTCiU&list=PLVKTjV4NoC88AHv6Q9063cpqS9QgCjRZB&index=3", you will find the Electron Configuration information where f-block has 14 spaces for 1 electron each. Each f-block is short by 1 electron each when compared with the number of elements in the Inner Table. This is why 5d1 is often utilized when writing out the Electron Configuration for Lanthanide for example.

Comment: I hope that the above will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken the Lanthanide and Actinides have 14 elements each, which match with the amount of electrons needed to fill the 4f block. You might be confused because they range from Lanthanum ([Xe]5d1 6s2) to Lutetium ([Xe] 4f14 5d1 6s2) on a peroidic table. The inclusion of Lutetium is because thats where the block would normally be replaced with an asterisk out of the table and so the element has to be shown somewhere.

Good example of a [periodic table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4q1r.png) which shows this, Lutetium (atomic number 71) would be normally placed next to Barium (atomic number 56).

Comment: https://applets.kcvs.ca/IPTEI/IPTEI.html

Comment: 1.the above URL will clearly show 15 elements for each of the Inner Periodic Table

Comment: 2.please note that your Noble Shorthand "Lanthanum ([Xe]5d1 6s2) to Lutetium ([Xe] 4f14 5d1 6s2) " shows that you used up all of the 14 places for 4f14 + plus an additional 5d1 for the shortfall of 1.

Comment: By the way lanthanum-57 comes after barium-56.